# Using multiple webviews in Android to simulate the Javascript threads

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview, dom-events, web-worker

I'm writing an Android app using webview. The app gets the data from the remote server and plots the data in html5 canvas. but while doing this I'm not able to use the UI controls. I thought of using the web workers but found that Android webview doesn't support web workers.

My question is if I use multiple webviews will it create separate js thread for each web View?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, javascript and web page layouting in all WebViews run on the same thread - WebViewCoreThread; although things may change in future Android versions.